# Git fetch части содержимого ветки

Tags: git, fetch

Подскажите, возможно ли сделать fetch удаленной ветки так, чтобы скачалось не все ее содержимое, а только выбранное? Например, в удаленном репозитории есть ветка master. В ней 3 файла. Мне надо поработать только с одним из них. Я создаю локальный репозиторий, создаю в нем remote origin на нужную мне удаленную ветку, а так же отслеживаемую ветку. Как теперь сделать fetch так, чтобы на локальную машину скачался только один файл (например, test.txt)?

Comment: вообще никак. от слова абсолютно. ведь команда fetch скачивает [объекты](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-Git), и к извлечению из них файлов не имеет ровно никакого отношения.

Comment: А вроде есть GUI программы, которые так умеют делать... Хотя они, наверное, просто скачивают все, но просто показывают только то, что хочет пользователь. Вот и создается впечатление, что скачалось не все содержимое ветки...

Comment: ещё раз: команда fetch не извлекает из объектов ничего. ни отдельный файл, ни два файла, ни три. вообще не извлекает. с помощью неё получают **объекты** из отдалённого хранилища и складируют их в локальное. ни на йоту больше.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения!

Comment: Можно попытаться через хуки сделать, но обычно это решается через submodule.